# Почему не срабатывает метод preventDefault()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

При выборе картинки ссылка не должна срабатывать, но все равно кидает на другую страницу. Второй день бьюсь. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть загвоздка?

Работаю в *PhpDesigner8*. Потому как в *WebStorm*'е выдает на `function(e)`

> unused parameter function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#small a').click(function(e) {
    $('#big img').hide().attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));

    $('#big img').load(function() {
      $(this).fadeIn(2000);
    });

    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gallery">
  <div id="big">
    <img src="images/gal/start.jpg" alt="Старт" />
  </div>
  <div id="small">
    <a href="images/gal/1.jpg">
      <img src="images/gal/1_mini.jpg" alt="Миниатюра 1" />
    </a>
    <a href="images/gal/2.jpg">
      <img src="images/gal/2_mini.jpg" alt="Миниатюра 2" />
    </a>
    <a href="images/gal/3.jpg">
      <img src="images/gal/3_mini.jpg" alt="Миниатюра 3" />
    </a>
    <a href="images/gal/4.jpg">
      <img src="images/gal/4_mini.jpg" alt="Миниатюра 4" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27870794/jquery-click-event-preventdefault-not-working

Comment: А ссылки динамически добавляются?

Comment: в приведенном сниппете все работает

Comment: Странное у вас аргументирование выбора IDE для разработки) Вам так сильно мешает серенькая подсветка одного символа в WebStorm?)

Comment: Наверное да. Вы, правы, я вернусь к WebStorm он более удобный.

Comment: @FoxOnTheRun и позвольте еще заострить внимание на `unused parameter function.`: с приведенным вами кодом переменная `e` в `function(e)` не должна быть помечена как unused. Вы точно не забыли `e.preventDefault()` в конце? Без него как раз появляется. А то, может быть, случайно удалили там или еще что-то такое... Всяко бывает.

Comment: Да я второй день с этим кодом сижу, десять раз уже переписан был. Сюда можно вставить скиншот?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как выяснилось в ходе обсуждения, вы используете версию jQuery 3.1.0.

Попробуйте заменить устаревший метод `.load(` на современное обращение `.on('load'`:

```
$('#big img').on('load',function() {
  $(this).fadeIn(2000);
});
```

На [странице официальной документации](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) можно увидеть, что `.load()` устарел в версии 1.8 и был удален в версии 3.0.

Собственно, все "event-методы" типа `.click()`, `.load()`, `.hover()`, etc давно уже рекомендуется заменять на унифицированный интерфейс `.on('eventName', function(){...})`.

Comment: Все заработало! Спасибо.

Comment: Вот так и учимся, по устаревшим методам.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз больше. Буду курить официальную документацию)

Comment: @FoxOnTheRun пожалуйста) Если что - мы всегда здесь, заходите ;)

Comment: @FoxOnTheRun отсюда мораль - если IDE что-то подчеркивает, это не просто так :)

Answer (score -1):

возможно, на момент присвоения триггера .click() ваших `#small a` в DOM еще не существует

поэтому попробуйте вместо

`$('#small a').click(function(e) {})`

использовать конструкцию

```
$('body').on("click", "#small a", function(e) {});
```

Comment: Я пытаюсь разобраться, почему не работает именно представленный код, когда в видео уроке, из которого он взять, все работает.

Comment: тогда полный html и js в студию, пожалуйста

Comment: Кусок html и весь js и есть

Comment: забавно. проверил в хроме этот код - все работает прекрасно

Comment: А что может быть не так тогда? И хром и ИЕ и ФФ одно и то же выдают

Comment: @FoxOnTheRun 1 - есть ли ошибки в консоли? 2 - откройте режим инкогнито в хроме и попробуйте там. 3 - я правильно понимаю, ссылки не должны работать, а у вас при клике по ним происходит переход? Здесь, в примере выше, появляющемся при нажатии кнопки "выполнить код" ?

Comment: Здесь не переходит. Смена режима в хроме не помогла. Я так понимаю дело в ссылке на библиотеку jQuery. Я просто полнейший нуб  в этом всем, стараюсь понять.

Comment: Вот, здесь работает верно. Уже прогресс. А "там" - это где? Проверить загрузку jQuery можно в DevTools, на вкладке Netwrok. И еще раз - проверьте консоль. Если проблема в jQuery - в консоли так и написано.

Comment: что пишет консоль хрома после того, как нажимаете на ссылку? покажите прямо скрин, пожалуйста.

Comment: В консоле все ок вроде. * jQuery JavaScript Library v3.1.0
 * https://jquery.com/

Comment: @FoxOnTheRun но у вас в коде подключена 2.1. Это где такая надпись про jQuery у вас?

Comment: В консоле фаерфокса.

Comment: @FoxOnTheRun покажите скриншот этой консоли. Как вы запускаете? У вас это все на локалхосте или где? Скриншот ссылкой.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/Qi0nb

Comment: При переходе по ссылке выдает такое

Comment: @FoxOnTheRun информативный скриншот, спасибо.

Comment: @FoxOnTheRun точно тот html, который показан в вопросе - это весь HTML?

Comment: @ДенисЖитняков сдается мне версия jQuery у него другая подключена, а в остальном, вероятно, все то же самое. В сниппете если версию 3.1.0 заюзать - та же проблема.